# PHP create image files from URL with GET attributes

Tags: php, image

Sorry guys if its a duplicate, I coudnt find similar topic. So, lets say there is a URL with image content, called "www.test.com/test.jpg".
I want to save the image to a folder using php, so I use

```
  file_put_contents('test.jpg', 'www.test.com/test.jpg');
```

and it is working fine, saving the image to the current folder. However, if the image URL looks like this:

```
  www.test.com/test.jpg?id={1a2b3c-4d5e6f}
```

I cannot use file_put_contents to save the image. If I try to remove the ?id={1a2b3c-4d5e6f} part, the browser wont open the image. Any ideas how to make the save successful?

Comment: What is the code you use to generate the image?

Comment: What do you get when you try to open the image? A 404? Or a broken image?

Comment: I get this -> HTTP status 400 - type Status report - The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect ().

Comment: Even without the query string? The query string is in fact syntactically incorrect, you have to urlencode the curly braces.

Comment: Are you sure that the image returned is not really corrupted?

Comment: @syck - i have a function to urlencode the data, using curl, i'll try to use it in the query

Comment: What size has the saved image? And if you want to get it from a remote URL, you should prefix the link with http://.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use the URI as filename. Potential issues with this go beyond what you have already found.

Instead, something like the following will work.

```
$uri = 'http://www.test.com/test.jpg?id={1a2b3c-4d5e6f}';
$data = file_get_contents($uri);
file_put_contents(md5($uri),$data);
```

If the original URI for the image is needed, store it in a DB or text file with a reference back to the MD5. Something like this might work (without testing).

```
$uri = 'http://www.test.com/test.jpg?id={1a2b3c-4d5e6f}';
$uriMd5 = md5($uri);
$data = file_get_contents($uri);
file_put_contents($uriMd5,$data);
file_put_contents($uriMd5.'.txt',$uri);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$variable="www.test.com/test.jpg?id={1a2b3c-4d5e6f}";
$variable=substr($variable, 0, strpos($variable, "?")); // www.test.com/test.jpg
file_put_contents('test.jpg', $variable);
```

Try this.

Comment: After removing the ?id= part, the URL to the image is broken.

Answer (score 0):

The solution: First, the function to get data:

```
    function getData($url) {
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url); 
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1 ); 

        $data = curl_exec( $ch ); 
        curl_close($ch);  

        if ($data) return $data; 
        else die("no data - ".$url);
    }
```

then use:

```
 file_put_contents('test.jpg', getData(..URL..));
```

Comment: I'd call it rather workarounded than solved. But storing data you retrieve from the web in folders with public access is risky: If someone masks the URL or hijacks the connection, they can place malicious code on your system and execute it. So make sure to store the images in a folder where no scripts are executed.